# Review Technical ETL process for knowledge management

Tags: sql-server, data-warehouse, business-intelligence

I'm looking for source code and all related component/material to review technical ETL process between source database and Data Warehouse in order to increase my knowledge in technical Business Intelligence. Where can I find these types of source code and database?

I can find the database for adventurework OLTP and its DW but not the source code for the ETL process

Comment: You've asled a number of very general questions - could you please elaborate on what you want to achieve.  Are you looking for an introduction to business intelligence/data warehousing, doing a course or what?

Comment: I want to achieve lots of knowledge in Microsoft BI. My context do not have in commen in schoolwork etc. Everything is based on my initiative for increasing learning curve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kimball Group books are great source of DW knowledge and ETL information in particular.

http://www.kimballgroup.com/html/booksMDWTtools.html

Follow this link, click **Tools and Utilities**, scroll to **Chapter 7 — Design and Develop the ETL System**.

Download **Sample SSIS packages** contains full solutions for Adventure Works.

Comment: Can you give any more information about this? Like, to clarify the what and all?

Comment: I got some mileage out of Kimball's ''The Data Warehouse Toolkit''.  It covers a number of common scenarios in a single volume, a great beginner-to-intermediate book.  I would caution that it describes idealized environments - don't expect a real-world DW to match the examples.